# translate c++ code into java

Tags: java, c++, pointers, struct, translation

I need to translate some c++ into java, but I have I few issues.

How to I have to deal with pointers when they are declared as arguments in the Method?

```
static void test( double *output){}
```

Also what is and how can I replace struct?

```
struct test { int t;
int arg;
float *pva;
double *array;
}
```

And then in the code they use:

```
double test(struct test *test)
{}
```

Oh and a last one.. this is also inside struct test, what means :

```
test->arg
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static void test( double *output){}
```

This needs more context, it can mean a pointer to a double or an array of doubles.

```
struct test { int t;
int arg;
float *pva;
double *array;
}
```

A `struct` is a `class` with default `public` access level. You can replace it with a class with `public` members.

```
test->arg
```

This accesses the `arg` member in `test`.

Answer (score 1):

You do not have pointers in Java, only references and only for objects (not for primitive types). References are like pointers, but you use the '.' notation instead of '*' or '->'. Also, you do not need to delete objects in Java, you just stop using them and eventually the garbage collector with destroy them.

Answering your points above, from bottom to top:
If test is a pointer to a struct or class in C++, and arg is a member variable of test, then

```
test->arg
```

is used to access the member through the pointer. This would map to

```
test.arg
```

in Java, if arg is a public member variable of the test object.

I would translate the following:

```
struct test
{
    int t;
    int arg;
    float *pva;
    double *array;
}

...

double test(struct test *test)
{}
```

to

```
public class Test
{
    public int t;

    public int arg;

    float [] pva;

    double [] array;
}

...

public static double test(Test test)
{}
```

For the first case, i.e. the function

```
static void test( double *output){}
```

you cannot pass a pointer to double and modify the double in Java. You have to return a double. If you need the double also as an input parameter, you specify it as a normal parameter that is passed by value:

```
static double test(double output)
{}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Or you could do it the c++ way, passing a double[] of size 1 and modifying its contents (useful when the method already has another return type)

Answer (score 0):

In the simple cases you can replace `float *` and `double *` with `float []` and `double []` However C++ allows you to do all sorts of unpleasant things which are difficult to translate into Java because it is not allowed in Java.

You can replace a `struct` with a `class`

If you want to understand basic C++ syntax, I suggest you read a guide on how to program in C++.

Comment: ... 'If you want to understand basic C++ syntax, I suggest you read a guide on how to program in C++' ... mmm

Comment: We can't be helping him translate line by line as C++ has many levels of complexity Java doesn't have.  He has be able able to read basic C++ code.

Comment: `void test(double * output)` can relate to either passing an array of double or passing a pointer to a single double where the output is written. The choice of name for the attribute seems to indicate the latter.

Comment: If you have a method with returns one double I would expect to be written as `double test()`.

Answer (score 0):

> (1) `static void test( double *output){}`

Here `double*` can be replaced with a `Double[]` (assume that you do a `new Double[]`) and the method can be put inside a `class`.

```
class testMethod {
  public static void test (Double []output) { }
}
```

> (2) how can I replace `struct`?
>   It can be replaced with a `class`.

```
class test {
public int t;
public int arg;
public Float []pva;
public Double []array;
}
```

> (3) `double test(struct test *test)  {}`
>   It can be,

```
double test (test t) {}
```

> (4) `test->arg`

Java doesn't have pointers (though it's implemented with reference); so above statement will be `test.arg`

Comment: Why would us use `Float[]` or `Double[]` instead of `float[]` or `double[]`?

Comment: I think you want `double` instead of `Double`. Similarly for `Float`.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, I assumed that the OP may want to do dynamic allocation in C++ (i.e. `new double[100]`). Which would be more suitable as `new Double[100]`, in Java.

Comment: In Java you can use new double[100] (array of primitive type double) or new Double[100] (array of Double objects). I do not see the advantage of using the second possibility, though.

Comment: The first case can relate to either passing an array of `double` or passing a pointer to a single double where the output is written. The choice of name for the attribute seems to indicate the latter.